# How can I bring my current Access DB to foreground via VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get my access db to come to the foreground based on the couple of lines, below. I'm not sure why it isn't working though, or if there are better methods to do this.

From what I've read, this should work:

```
Access.Visible = False
Access.Visible = True
```

But doesn't actually bring the database to the front.

Edit for more info:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    getStrUserName = Environ("username")

    dbName = "myDB.accdb" ' database name
    versionChckDB = "versionCheckDB.accdb" ' version check db name
    strServer = "C:\My\Path\to\Server" ' server location string
    strDesktop = "C:\My\Path\to\Local" ' desktop location string
    strVersionCheck = "C:\My\Path\to\Version" ' version check location

    Static acc As Access.Application
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strDbName As String

    If FileLocked(strDesktop & "\" & versionChckDB) Then
        Dim objAccess As Access.Application
        Set objAccess = GetObject(strDesktop & "\" & versionChckDB)
        objAccess.Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
        Set objAccess = Nothing
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainMenu"
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
        Access.Visible = False
        Access.Visible = True
        GoTo exitSub
    Else
        strDbName = strDesktop & "\" & versionChckDB
        Set acc = New Access.Application
        acc.Visible = True
        Set db = acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDbName, False, False)
        acc.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbName
    End If
    'db.Close
    exitSub:
        Call SetForegroundWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp) ' bringing access DB to foreground

    End Sub
```

Comment: What Access application instance do you want as the foreground window? `SetForegroundWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp)`  should make the one which contains that `Form_Open` code the foreground window.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @HansUp I want the current database (from the perspective of the code) to come to the foreground, correct.

Comment: What happens if you open the other database like this (instead of using `Set acc = New Access.Application`)? --> `Shell """" & SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "MSACCESS.EXE" & """ """ & strDbName & """"`

Comment: Make sure space included: `"MSACCESS.EXE" & """ """ & strDbName & """"`

Comment: @HansUp That seems to have fixed it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ah, interesting. I tested with `Shell` too. Thanks @HansUp !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually one uses an API function for that.

From http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=132129 :

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
```

and then

```
Call SetForegroundWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp)
```

**Edit**
If you want to get the newly opened Access application window to the front, you need its `hWnd`:

```
Call SetForegroundWindow(acc.hWndAccessApp)
```

**Edit 2**
This works for me. Notepad is briefly in the foreground, then the Access window.

Module:

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub TestAccessToForeground()

    Sleep 300
    Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
    Sleep 300
    Call SetForegroundWindow(Application.hWndAccessApp)

End Sub
```

Form:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Call TestAccessToForeground

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get the following error after adding the declaration:

`The expression On Open you entered..... Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules`


Edit: Changed declaration to private, began working. Still doesn't bring it to the foreground, though.

Comment: Put that declaration in a standard module.  Then you can call it from any other code in your application.

Comment: @HansUp That makes sense, but it still didn't bring the application to the foreground.

Comment: I think we'll need to see some context. Please show us how you're call that API function.

Comment: @Ryan_W4588: How / where are you calling the API function? Is the Access window hidden behind other windows, or minimized? In the latter case, you'll need a different function.

Comment: @HansUp updated my OP. Andre, the window is hidden behind other folders/applications if they are open at the time of calling.