# Center Microsoft Access VBA Forms in The Screen on Initialization

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, centering, windows-forms-designer

How would I get the screen width and height in Microsoft Access VBA?

I have searched for the 'Screen' and 'Application' global instances, but none of those contain member fields for width or height parameter (or any variants of the those words I know, such as WindowWidth/WindowHeight ...etc.).

My main intention here is to initialize a form instance at the center of the screen by using the screen's width and height (which I want to find), and modify the form's WindowLeft and WindowTop accordingly. If there is a better approach, would you mind direct me to it, as I personally did not find any way to approach that in an easy way in the form's properties in the designer.

Comment: I have looked at that posting before, but UsableHeight and UsableWidth are not properties of Application. Why is this the case?

Comment: Why are you asking me why MS did not provide those properties? I'm not Microsoft, and I didn't design Access. If you want to know why Microsoft made a decision, contact http://support.microsoft.com and ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ken White has highlighted this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843310/how-to-retrieve-screen-size-resolution-in-ms-access-vba-to-re-size-a-form#11843637) demonstrates a good approach.

In regards to a ScreenWidth and ScreenHeight being missing as properties of the Access Application, whilst that is true there is always `hWndAcesssApp` which returns a Window handle which can then be used to interrogate properties (and indeed set properties) of the Application Window.  Here are links which make use of `hWndAccessApp` |[how bring ms-access form top all windows application](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/959950-how-bring-ms-access-form-top-all-windows-application)|[hiding access 2007 interface](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/office-software/52667-hiding-access-2007-interface-vba.html)|[how-can-i-bring-my-current-access-db-to-foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835809/how-can-i-bring-my-current-access-db-to-foreground-via-vba#answer-37836143)|